# function is undefined in firefox only

Tags: javascript, firefox

ok, the following code works ok in IE7+ and Chrome.
but for some reason, `xfade` is undefined in firefox

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="slider"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
var Klimateka = {
    Slider: function () {
        // Check if we have a slider div on page
        var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
        if (slider != null) {
            var images = ["slide-image-1.jpg", "slide-image-2.jpg", "slide-image-3.jpg", "slide-image-4.jpg"];
            var i = images.length;
            while (i) {
                i -= 1;
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = "images/" + images[i];
                slider.appendChild(img);
            }
            var d = document, imgs = new Array(), zInterval = null, current = 0, pause = false;
            imgs = d.getElementById("slider").getElementsByTagName("img");
            for (i = 1; i < imgs.length; i++) imgs[i].xOpacity = 0;
            imgs[0].style.display = "block";
            imgs[0].xOpacity = .99;

            setTimeout("xfade()", 3500);

            function xfade() {
                cOpacity = imgs[current].xOpacity;
                nIndex = imgs[current + 1] ? current + 1 : 0;

                nOpacity = imgs[nIndex].xOpacity;

                cOpacity -= .05;
                nOpacity += .05;

                imgs[nIndex].style.display = "block";
                imgs[current].xOpacity = cOpacity;
                imgs[nIndex].xOpacity = nOpacity;

                setOpacity(imgs[current]);
                setOpacity(imgs[nIndex]);

                if (cOpacity <= 0) {
                    imgs[current].style.display = "none";
                    current = nIndex;
                    setTimeout(xfade, 3500);
                } else {
                    setTimeout(xfade, 50);
                }

                function setOpacity(obj) {
                    if (obj.xOpacity > .99) {
                        obj.xOpacity = .99;
                        return;
                    }
                    obj.style.opacity = obj.xOpacity;
                    obj.style.MozOpacity = obj.xOpacity;
                    obj.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (obj.xOpacity * 100) + ")";
                }
            }
        }
    },

    bar: function () {
    }
}; 

Klimateka.Slider();
```

i have setup a jsfiddler for testing:
http://jsfiddle.net/rTtKh/10/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This might only apply to Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#function_oddities):

> functions do not hoist when declared inside a child block.

You declare `xfade` inside the `if` block, but you are calling it prior to the declaration:

```
setTimeout(xfade, 3500);
```

Put the function declaration on top.

<del>You have to do the same with `setOpacity` inside `xfade`.</del> `<-` That is not necessary.

Comment: Ahhhh haaaaa. got it ^_^.  that makes sense :-D

Comment: Yes - also it'd be a really good idea to make sure all those variables in "xfade()" are properly declared with `var` at whatever scope level is appropriate.

Comment: @Pointy - i think you missed it, since they are declared.

Comment: @Felix - that fixed the problem, but i was sure FF is standard compliant.

Comment: @Dementic I don't see a `var` declaration for "cOpacity", "nIndex", and "nOpacity".

Comment: @Dementic: I don't know whether is anything mentioned in the specification regarding this behaviour. If someone finds it, I'd be glad. But not every behaviour is defined in the specification.

Comment: @Dementic Per the standard, having a `function` statement inside an `if` should throw a `SyntaxError` exception and stop parsing the script.  All browsers deviate from the standard here by extending the JS syntax to allow such `function` statements inside `if` blocks, but they have subtly different behavior for these extensions.  Had you stuck to writing valid JavaScript code, you wouldn't have run into the problems with those different behaviors....

Answer (score 1):

Fix your line that says this: `setTimeout("xfade()", 3500);` to match your others:

```
setTimeout(xfade, 3500);
```

Comment: The fiddle already uses this version, but the error is still there.

Comment: I wonder what makes it work in IE and Chrome. I know that IE does some bizarre things with named function *expressions*, but that "xfade" function is just a regular function declaration. *edit* - ah. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout(xfade, 3500) instead.